# Best way to align vertically <div> with different flex directions?

Tags: html, css

I several 'div' in my 'body' and
I'd like to vertically center the items inside those 'div' but some of them has column as flex-direction.

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

body div{
    flex: 1;
}
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: RGB(230, 230, 230);
    align-items: center;
}

.header ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.description {
    background-color: RGB(200, 200, 200);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.img {
    max-width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}

.information {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: RGB(170, 170, 170);
    align-items: center;
}

.information .card {
    display: flex;
}

.quotes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: RGB(130, 130, 130);
    align-items: center;
}

.signup {
    display: flex;
    background-color: RGB(100, 100, 100);
    align-items: center;
}

.footer {
    display: flex;
    background-color: RGB(70, 70, 70);
    align-items: center;
}
```

what would be the best way to align vertically the items inside those 'div'?
Should I just individually do that or is there any better way to do so?

Comment: If you have flex direction as column then ```justify-content: center``` would align them vertically

Comment: `body div {` is dangerous CSS. That one line will target every. single. DIV. no matter how deep. Almost just like `div {` Please, take care of what you're writing.

Comment: What would you recommend using rather than body div{} ? is * {} is a better option?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`, but in this case you may want to check out [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 0):

in the css class you can add multiple css blocks

with the footer section it would be

```
class="footer"
```

so add a align class with .align

```css
.align{
    align-items:center;
}
```

then change `class="footer"` to `class="footer align"`

Comment: `.align{` might have a meaning to you. I know that *naming things* is hard, but that one is not descriptive enough.

Comment: So, I'll be making two different classes for each of the direction? did I understand correctly? and also following the comment from above, If body {} is dangerous, what would you recommend to use instead? is * {} a better option ? thank you very much